# Getters and setters in abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract-class, setter, getter, getter-setter

I'm working on a game in Java and I have a problem with using setters and getters from an abstract class. Let's say the class looks like this:

```
public abstract class Objects {
    protected int velX, velY;

    public Objects(int velX, int velY){
        this.velX = velX;
        this.velY = velY;
    }

    //getters, setters and other methods
}
```

Now, if I want to use these methods in a class that does not extend abstract class Objects, it does not work properly. The game will run but it throws NullPointerException when it tries to execute the part of the code with getters and setters. For example:

```
public class HUD {
    private Objects o;

    public HUD(......)

    public void someMethod(){
        if (o.getVelX > 0){
            o.setVelY(3);
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a bad example, but if I ran this it would throw a NullPointerException. Do I have to initialize the class Objects in a different way?

Comment: Yes, you need to instantiate `Objects` to execute getter/setters, provided getter/setters are public.

Comment: is Objects o initialized in the constructor HUD(..........) ? Otherwise it will be null and you will get nullpointerexception

Comment: Yes they are public. I cannot instantiate Objects, since it is abstract. I do not call super() in HUD constructor

Comment: To make use of the abstract class you need to subclass it. Then the `getVelX()`, if public or protected method behaves like it was in your class. If the relationship between Objects and HUD isn't a [is-a relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a), overthink your class design.

Comment: The point of an abstract class is that you need to instantiate a subclass to make use of it. If you're not instantiating a subclass, make it not abstract and instantiate the class itself.

Comment: There are actually 4 subclasses that extend Objects.

Comment: If you have 4 subclasses then you need to instantiate the proper subclass in HUD.

Comment: And if I want to use more than one subclass i just do it like private Objects o, o1, o2, o3 and then this.o = new player(), this.o1 = new enemy()...?

Answer (score 0):

I order to use `o`, you must initialize it with a reference to an instance of a concrete class that extends your Objects abstract class. Otherwise `o` remains null, and any call to `o.something` throws `NullPointerException`. This has nothing to do with setters or getters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new not abstract class for exmaple `ObjectsChild`and after that  initialize your `o` object first, in constructor `HUD()` for example:

```
private Objects o;

public HUD() {
    this.o = new ObjectsChild();
}
```

After that you can invoke getters and setters on this `o` object.

Comment: Isn't `Objects` abstract and he **can't** create an instance?

Comment: Yep, I cannot do this.

Comment: @wonderb0lt look at my update, you can initialize an instance of an abstract class, you just need to implement all abstract methods inplace.

Answer (score 0):

When defining non-primitive fields, thair default value is null, so your o field is null. You need to initialize it in your constructor, or at least before you are calling any method on it.

```
public class HUD {
    private Objects o;

    public HUD(......){
       o = new Objects();//or a class that extends your abstract Objects class
    }

public void someMethod(){
    // at this poing you need to have o initialized
    if (o.getVelX > 0){
        o.setVelY(3);
    }
}
}
```

**UPDATE**:

You can initialize `Objects` instance, but this will be an annonymous class and you will need to implement all abstract methods in this place:

```
o = new Objects(){
   @Override
   public void myAbstractMethod(){
     ...
   }
}
```

As for NPE, you could use [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) from guava or JDK8 to avoid it.